# Get rid off single quotes in db_query() drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I need to execute following query

```
switch($interval) {
case "1 month":
$interval = "1 month";
break:
case "1 year":
$interval = "1 year";
break:
}

db_query("SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <=    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :interval)", array(":interval" => $interval))
```

This query throws a sql error and because you can see single quote is added around '1 month'

**Executed query:**
    SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1 month')

**Expected query**:
    SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)

Any ideas around how do I get rid off single quotes?

Comment: have you echoed the query before running db_query

Comment: If you have trusted parameter value for $interval variable (e.g. it doesn't come from user instead you fill it) you can place it within the sql string instead of bind it, like this: `db_query("SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <=    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {$interval})")`

Comment: @Zaragoli if you run INTERVAL {$interval} then this is how sql is executed."SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $interval)" which again throws sql error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trusted parameter value for $interval variable (e.g. it doesn't come from user instead you fill it) you can place it within the sql string instead of bind it, like this:

```
$interval = "1 year";
db_query("SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {$interval})");
```

It will run the next sql query:

```
string(95) "SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 year)"
```

(use double quotes instead of single around sql string to let the PHP interpreter to evaluate the nested variable)